# Find a polynomial of 4-th degree where the derivatives are given

Tags: calculus, polynomials

I'm having a problem with polynomials:
Let $$ f(x) = e^x $$
Find a fourth degree polynomial p(x) where
$$ p(0) = f(0) $$
$$ p'(0) = f'(0)$$
$$ p''(0) = f''(0)$$
$$ p'''(0) = f'''(0)$$
From the definiton of $$\frac{d}{dx} e^x $$we have that all four derivatives of p(x) are supposed to be 1. So the question is, how do I convert that information to a polynom?

Answer (score 5):

Hint: use the Taylor polynomial. You can just take:
$$
p(x)=\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+x+1.
$$